# PHP CLI does not use additional .ini files

Tags: php

I can't seem to find an answer as to why when I run PHP from the CLI, the additional ini files options is set to none. I'm aware that when I use the `-c` flag, I can specify a particular config file to load, however, I haven't been able to find a flag to specify the directory to load ini files from. Is there a flag to do this? Or is there a file I can edit to specify the location of the ini directory?

Here's what running `php -i` produces:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to recompile PHP to enable that, for example:

```
./configure ... --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d
```

Comment: @SAHIL.R2050 xampp should come with its own hardcoded configuration path, since it ships with bundled PHP